# How to implement Server Sent Events with Nuxt?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-sent-events

I want to send data unidirectional from server to client. I could not find any documentation on nuxt.js website on how to go about this. I found only [1 issue on their Github Repo](https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/36) and a very [vague article on the same](https://damienbeaufils.dev/blog/server-sent-events-with-nuxt-js-vue-js-and-nginx-proxy/).

How to push server sent events from an express API in nuxt to vuex store or component in the frontend?

Comment: you means something like `websockets` ? send event to client from server?

Comment: no websockets are bidirectional, server sent events are unidirectional, thats all i know :)